# ivars when mixing C and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

I'm writing an Objective-C wrapper for a C library and having problems accessing the references of my ivars.

The C library requires that I specify a function pointer that handles events, I specify it during the initialization of my Objective-C class.

```
- (id) init {
    [super init];
    RegisterClient(&handleEvent);
    return self;
}
```

The C library is able to start searching for something and will then call the handleEvent function in case anything happened during the search. The function (basically) looks like this.

```
int handleEvent(void *Event) {
    [delegate didFinishSearching];
    return 0;
}
```

At least I'd wish it looked like this. The problem is that the code won't build because `'delegate' undeclared (first use in function)` (of course I have declared it, I can call `[delegate didFinishSearching]` from any Objective-C method but not from a C function). Older questions from stackoverflow suggest to define an additional variable (e.g. `theDelegate`) in the header file:

```
id theDelegate;

@interface Controller : NSObject {
    id delegate;
}
@property (assign) id delegate;
@end
```

Then, whenever I change the value of `delegate` to a new one, I have to assign this value to `theDelegate`, too.

Since my C is somewhat rusty, here are my questions:

1) Can I pass the `RegisterClient` C function a pointer to an Objective-C method instead of a pointer to a function as an argument in order to avoid the C function `handleEvent` completely?

2) If not: When I create multiple instances of this Objective-C class, will `theDelegate` be the same for all instances? (After all, it's not declared as an instance variable...)

Comment: the void *Event parameter-- what is it?  If it's something you passed in as a context parameter-ish thing, you could just pass the delegate.

Comment: The void *Event parameter contains details about the event. But you made a helpful remark: `int handleEvent(void  *Event)` is actually `int handleEvent(void *Event, void *Cookie)`. When starting the search I can pass anything I'd like as a "cookie" and in case of an event it will appear in the handleEvent function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C methods are C functions, but they have two hidden parameters at the front, so they won't have the `int f(void *)` signature.

What you probably want to do is use an libffi closure. That allows you to create a function with exactly the signature that you want, but that also has a pointer to your object passed along with it. See the example in the [`ffi_prep_closure` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/ffi_prep_closure.3.html). Your `handleEvent` function would probably then change to look something like this:

```
static void handleEventClosure(ffi_cif * cif, void * result, void ** args, void * userdata)
{
    // Arguments.
    void * Event = *args[0];

    // Closed-over data.
    id delegate = (id)userdata;

    // Execute the method.
    [delegate didFinishSearching];

    // Smaller than sizeof(long), so use ffi_arg or ffi_sarg (unsigned or signed).
    *(ffi_sarg *)result = (ffi_sarg)0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time C Libraries like the one you describe accept a "userinfo" parameter conveniently size to match a pointer. You can use this to your advantage by passing your object as this "userinfo" parameter.

Then in callbacks, you cast the pointer back to an object and make the calls you need.